# Critical vulnerability with pip:23.2.1 in Xray Scan

Tags: python, docker, pip, alpine-linux, jfrog-xray

There is a critical vulnerability with our Docker image where we are not using Python at all

```bash
FROM alpine:3.18.4

RUN apk add nfs-utils
RUN rc-update add nfsmount
```

Python is a dependency which is added as part of `nfs-unit` in our Docker image

When Xray scans the Docker image we see that there is a critical vulnerability.

We tried adding and installing pip in version 23.3 using

```bash
RUN apk --no-cache  --latest upgrade py3-pip
```

But, the same vulnerability is still reported.

How do we solve it?

Reference: https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2018-20225

Answer (score 1):

CVE-2018-20225 is affecting all pip versions and will not be fixed as its an intended behavior by pip (The vulnerability is disputed by [NVD](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-20225))

Xray finds it as part of pip and this will not be changed but there is an improvement soon to better display disputed vulnerabilities.

If you don't --extra-index-url inside your docker project, As mentioned in the vulnerability description, you will not be affected and can create an ignore rule for this vulnerability on all pip versions.

Comment: When customers scan the docker image and see this same high/critical vulnerability and they come back is there any official documentation which describes handling these types of issues?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.
You can add an ignore rule which affects all your instance for this vulnerability:
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-security-documentation/ignore-rules

You can also see the description and jfrog-research if available and decide on the resolution if needed:
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-security-documentation/jfrog-security-cve-research-and-enrichment

Comment: @VinayKumarByrappa, as pointed in the answer, the CVE is disputed, see https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-20225 and the corresponding link on the _DISPUTED_ word https://www.cve.org/ResourcesSupport/FAQs#pc_cve_recordsdisputed_signify_in_cve_recordresponse

Comment: We did this RUN rm /usr/lib/python3.11/ensurepip/_bundled/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
RUN rm /usr/lib/python3.11/ensurepip/_bundled/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl and we dont see the vulnerabilities anymore